# Clone the session cookie for another domain in Symfony2

Tags: php, session, symfony, cookies, symfony-2.4

I'm looking for a working solution, to set a secure clone of the session cookie for another domain in a different Symfony2 environment. My idea is, to set a cloned cookie just after a user logged in, so that the user can be authenticated in two different Symfony2 environments on two different domains.

```
Domain: mysite-a.com        // Environment -e site
Domain: api.mysite-b.com    // Environment -e api
```

Where to find something like a *controller* or *event* (best solution) to hook in?

I'm using the latest `2.x.dev` version of `FOSUserBundle`.

I know, this configuration is pretty ugly. Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to
change the Domain-Configuration from `api.mysite-b.com` to `api.mysite-a.com` (aka. wildcard-cookies).

Comment: could you solve this problem?

Comment: @ghostika Unfortunately, no. You can vote this question up (bump) or start a bounty.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no proper bundle to handle this problem, but in PHP specification you can find an accurate option to manage your problem `$domain`

```
bool setcookie ( string $name [, string $value [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] );
```

In symfony2 you ened to use Cookie object:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;

$response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('foo', 'bar'));
```

Cookie constructor has the same options as PHP method:

```
public function __construct($name, $value = null, $expire = 0, $path = '/', $domain = null, $secure = false, $httpOnly = true)
```

regards,

Comment: I don't think you can create a cookie on another domain. It may allow anybody to create a cookie to impersonate someone on any site.

Comment: But it's not "any" domain, but your own subdomain.

Comment: `api.mysite-b.com` is a subdomain of `api.mysite-b.com`. But `api.mysite-b.com` and `mysite-a.com` are not the same domain. So I don't think it will work for this question.

Comment: @n.1 Yes, I know that both domains are different - that's what I'm asking for. Usually you can simply use a wildcard cookie with a domain for ".mysite-a.com". Please read my notice beyond my question: I'm not allowed to change the Domain-Configuration, so I'm looking for a simple alternative. **Both domains run on the same server and use the same symfony2 instance.**

Comment: I was only replying to @PiotrPasich, I knew that the 2 domains are different. This is why I wanted to point the fact this answer may not work.

Comment: @PiotrPasich I'm sorry, but this is **not a solution**.